# SQL - Add up all row-values of one column in a singletable

Tags: sql, sum, hsqldb

I've got a question regarding a SQL-select-query:
The table contains several columns, one of which is an Integer-column called "size" - the task I'm trying to perform is query the table for the sum of all rows (their values), or to be more exact get a artifical column in my ResultSet called "overallSize" which contains the sum of all "size"-values in the table. Preferable it would be possible to use a WHERE-clause to add only certain values ("WHERE bla = 5" or something similar).

The DB-engine is HSQLDB (HyperSQL), which is compliant to SQL2008.

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
SELECT SUM(size) AS overallSize FROM table WHERE bla = 5;
```

Answer (score 11):

It's not as simple as this, is it?

```
SELECT SUM(SIZE)
FROM Table
WHERE bla = '5'
```

Comment: Yes, it works like a charm :) Thank you!

I knew it would be simple, but this :D

Answer (score 3):

Are you looking for:

```
SELECT SUM(Size) FROM MyTable WHERE bal = '5'
```

You can also (in MSSQL)

```
SELECT Size, COl1, COl2 FROM MyTable WHERE bla ='5' COMPUTE SUM(Size)
```

Comment: That's a new one on my, the calculate syntax.  Vote up for that.

Comment: Although, having looked, should the keyword not be COMPUTE?