# Add up all the values in a column

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, count

> **Possible duplicate of:** [SQL - Add up all row-values of one column in a singletable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2628159/sql-add-up-all-row-values-of-one-column-in-a-singletable)

This might sound a really easy question but I cant see to find a answer that works.

Ive a column in a table that is called 'timeId' 'talktime' 'holdtime' and 'call count'

There are 200+ rows in this table each with a call count. For example

```
TimeId     talktime    holdtime   CallCount    
1            20           40         3
2            105          9          6
3            433          43         12
4            403          44         15
5            199          85         22
```

How can i run a query to add up all the values in call count? but without grouping?

Thanks

Comment: So what should the answer look like?

Comment: what will be your desired output?

Comment: what version of SQL Server?

Comment: just a figure will be the answer and SQL server 2012

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want to get the sum of all counts you can use this:

```
SELECT SUM(CallCount) FROM MyTbl;
```

If you want the total together with the other values you can use the OVER clause:

```
SELECT *, SUM(CallCount)OVER()
FROM MyTbl;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT sum(CallCount) FROM myTable
```

Assuming `CallCount` is a numerical data type.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select [Total call count] = Sum([call count]) From [your table]
```

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT SUM(CallCount) FROM tblname`

Comment: How is this not an answer?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  a.*,
        b.TotalCount
FROM    TableName a
        CROSS JOIN
        (
            SELECT  SUM(CallCount) TotalCount -- Calculates all CallCount
            FROM    TableName
        ) b
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/04be1/1)

OUTPUT

```
╔════════╦══════════╦══════════╦═══════════╦════════════╗
║ TIMEID ║ TALKTIME ║ HOLDTIME ║ CALLCOUNT ║ TOTALCOUNT ║
╠════════╬══════════╬══════════╬═══════════╬════════════╣
║      1 ║       20 ║       40 ║         3 ║         58 ║
║      2 ║      105 ║        9 ║         6 ║         58 ║
║      3 ║      433 ║       43 ║        12 ║         58 ║
║      4 ║      403 ║       44 ║        15 ║         58 ║
║      5 ║      199 ║       85 ║        22 ║         58 ║
╚════════╩══════════╩══════════╩═══════════╩════════════╝
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your version of SQL Server you might be able to use [`SUM() Over()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx) which is a windowing function:

```
select Timeid, 
  talktime, 
  holdtime, 
  callcount,
  sum(callcount) over() TotalCalls
from yourtable
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5fccb/1)